# Cheking SSD health

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, smart

Recently I had a SMART error show up on one of my conventional hard drives and I was able to save the drive and back up the data in time before the drive was inaccessible.

I was wondering does SMART work for SSDs as well? From what I have read online it does not.

I also read that Samsung has a software called "Samsung magician", that keeps track of the read/write cycles of an SSD and will warn you before the limit is crossed.

Is the "Samsung Magician" software any useful, in short, I want to play it safe and want to detect before my drive goes bad.

Thanks

Comment: Beware that different manufacturers have entirely different controllers and software... Magician only works on Samsung SSDs, and not all manufacturers will make a utility as straightforward for their devices.  I mention because you haven't explicitly said that you are using Samsung.

Answer (score 2):

Modern science has not reached the point where it can reliably predict failure of electronic devices. SMART warnings are a step in that direction but it has many limitations. SMART will measure writes to the drive and a few other things but there are other issues it cannot measure. Excessive writes are no longer a major factor in SD failure which typically fail for other reasons. There are known reasons for SSD failure that cannot be predicted and I am sure others that are currently unknown.

I would consider SMART as less useful with an SSD than conventional drives. With conventional drives there is often some warning of impending failure and in many cases this is sufficient to backup your data. But never rely on this. But SSDs often fail totally and without warning or apparent cause.

Think of SMART warnings as the "check engine" light in a car. When present such warnings should be heeded but their lack does not mean all is well.

The only way to play itself with any drive, conventional or SSD, is to maintain backups. There may be no warnings of failure or it may come too late to be useful.

Comment: _Verified_ backups. Make sure to compare the checksums of files on the backup media against the source files checksums. A backup with errors is no backup at all.

Answer (score 1):

SSDs report SMART info as well, including some SSD-specific values that don't make sense for HDDs. Samsung Magician simply keeps tabs on SSD wear by looking at SMART values. Other SSD manufacturers also have their tools for this, for example Storage Executive from Crucial.

Modern SSDs are really hard to kill with regular usage, you probably shouldn't be afraid of SSD wear. Other than that, SSDs generally fail instantly and don't get worse slowly like HDDs do (although SSDs are more reliable overall).

If you want to be certain you won't loose your data, you should have backups, update them often and make sure they are restorable. The 3-2-1 rule says that you should have all data in 3 copies on 2 kinds of media (eg. SSD + HDD or SSD + DVDs), including 1 in remote location.

I'd recommend to install a tool from your SSD's manufacturer anyway because it can be used to upgrade drive's firmware, possibly increasing security, reliability and remaining lifetime. Make backups before doing this.